# Bold font style on Telerik Report returns to regular font style when exported as PDF

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I created a report using Telerik and something went wrong when I tried exporting the generated report as PDF. Some texts on my report are set to font style Bold, they're doing fine on my report viewer (which can be viewed on a browser) but when I tried exporting and downloading my report into a PDF file, the texts that I set to Bold font style became a regular font style. Is there something wrong on my report? Or is it on the PDF or the browser that I am using?

Additional info:
Reporting Tool: Telerik Q3 2014 V. 14.3.1118.0
Browser: Google Chrome V. 40.0.2214.94
PDF Reader: Adobe Reader XI V. 11.0.10
Programming Language: VB

Comment: Have a look here about exporting and formatting http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-pdf-export.html

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with the link you have provided to me, I'm only using Telerik Reporting. Thank you for the help, anyways